# Git: How to overwrite local change?

Tags: git, restore

I use git clone from github and I deleted some files & modified some files. Now I want to keep my local code & restore to the original form. Is there a command to achieve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to save you changes first, you can commit them before and then checkout you code to previous commit(s):
`git checkout HEAD^` (one commit back)
`git checkout GEAD~2` (2 commits back)

Or, if you don't need your changes anymore, run `git reset --hard HEAD`

Answer (score 8):

`git checkout <name of file>`

If you want to check out the whole repository, then from the root directory use

`git checkout .`

Comment: This didnt work for me.  for some unknown reason, it says a swf file I haven't changed is modified, and lists it as a change to be committed.  I tried doing "git checkout path/filename.swf", which it does with no errors, then when I do git status, it still lists the file as locally modified.  Any ideas?.  If this was SVN, I would simply delete the file, and do another checkout which would bring down the latest version.  I cant find a way to do this with git.

Answer (score 1):

`git reset --hard`

Answer (score 1):

Git command to pull all changes from branch by overwriting all local changes:-

```
git reset --hard HEAD
git pull
```

Answer (score -1):

You can remove local changes by this command

```
git clean -f
```

and pull changes by:

```
git pull
```